# Lower Sums $\le$ Integral $\le$ Upper Sums implies ? (Spivak pp 247, 249, Abbott pp 195,196)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> I question these two theorems together because I believe same problem?
>
> **1.** I don't understand how to conclude $\color{red}{I, II}$.  I see in both theorems, the overhead lines are Lower Sums (f, P) $\le$  Integral $\le$ Upper Sums (f, P). Then? Related to Theorem 1.2.6 beneath?
>
> **2.** Abbott says 'there is a way to use the [Algebraic Limit Theorem](http://www.math.byu.edu/%7Ebakker/M341/Lectures/Lec05.pdf) for' T7.4.2. But Spivak and he don't use it? Doesn't it simplify? Anyone know where there's a proof please? I tried to find it.

[image]![image]

Comment: Both reduce to a statement of the form, "If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers such that $\alpha - \varepsilon < \beta < \alpha + \varepsilon$ (i.e., $|\alpha - \beta| < \varepsilon$) for every $\varepsilon > 0$, then $\alpha = \beta$". For starters, are you convinced this implication is true?

Comment: @user86418 are you referring to theorem 1.2.6? i put it at the end now.

Comment: You've got a complete answer from Yiorgos, but in the spirit of hints: The inequalities before I. imply that if $\alpha=\int_a^b f$ and $\beta=\int_a^c f + \int_c^b f$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$, you have $|\alpha - \beta| < \varepsilon$. Claim II. can be expressed similarly.

Comment: @user86418 please answer too? Yiorgos's answer is different, ergo I'm content for different answers.

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain I.

Assume that $f$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. In order to show that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ we need to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$.

Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, then there exist partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ of $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, respectively, such that
$$
U(f,P_1)-L(f,P_1)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad
U(f,P_2)-L(f,P_2)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
It is next straight-forward that for the partition $P=P_1\cup P_2$
$$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon.
$$
Also
$$
L(f,P_1)\le\int_a^c f\le U(f,P_1)\quad\text{and}\quad
L(f,P_2)\le\int_c^b f\le U(f,P_2),
$$
and hence
$$
L(f,P_1)+L(f,P_2)=L(f,P)\le\int_a^c f+\int_c^b f\le U(f,P)=U(f,P_1)+U(f,P_2).
$$
Thus
$$
\sup_P L(f,P)\le\int_a^c f+\int_c^b f\le \inf_Q U(f,Q)
$$
and as $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, and thus $\sup_P L(f,P)=\inf_Q U(f,Q)=\int_a^b f$, then
$$
\int_a^c f+\int_c^b f =\int_a^b f.
$$

Comment: thanks. what's Q? and does your answer relate to user86418's comment and theorem 1.2.6?